# Why does 'add_assign' in a lambda function require marking the lambda function variable as mutable, but 'add' with manual assignment doesn't?

Tags: lambda, rust

Why in case of `add` function `mut` keyword is not mandatory, but in case of `add_assign` it's mandatory?

```
use std::ops::{Add, AddAssign};

let mut ssa = String::new();
let rr = move || { // no mut for rr is needed
    ssa = ssa.add("ds");
    println!("{}", ssa);
};
rr();

let mut ssa = String::new();
let mut rr = move || { // mut is mandatory
    ssa.add_assign("ds");
    println!("{}", ssa);
};
rr();
```

Answer (score 4):

A closure desugars into an anonymous struct that implements the `Fn` traits (`std::ops::{Fn, FnOnce, FnMut}` as possible, see more [in the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/closure.html). Your first closure implements only `FnOnce`. Your second implements `FnMut`, too).

To understand what's happening here, let's desugar the closures ourselves (note: correct desugaring requires nightly, since implementing the `Fn*` traits is unstable):

```rust
struct Closure1 {
    ssa: String,
}
impl FnOnce<()> for Closure1 {
    type Output = ();
    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(mut self, (): ()) {
        self.ssa = Add::add(self.ssa, "ds");
        println!("{}", self.ssa);
    }
}

let /*mut*/ ssa = String::new();
let rr = Closure1 { ssa };
FnOnce::call_once(rr, ());

struct Closure2 {
    ssa: String,
}
impl FnOnce<()> for Closure2 {
    type Output = ();
    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(mut self, (): ()) {
        FnMut::call_mut(&mut self, ())
    }
}
impl FnMut<()> for Closure2 {
    extern "rust-call" fn call_mut(&mut self, (): ()) {
        AddAssign::add_assign(&mut self.ssa, "ds");
        println!("{}", self.ssa);
    }
}
let /*mut*/ ssa = String::new();
let mut rr = Closure2 { ssa };
FnMut::call_mut(&mut rr, ());
```

[Playround](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b47408f993958cd383986c05f70e5b7e).

What do we have here?

The first closure calls [`<String as Add>::add()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#method.add). This method takes ownership of the `String`, and so it can only implement `FnOnce`, because it should move out of `self`.

On the other hand, the second closure calls [`<String as AddAssing>::add_assign()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#method.add_assign). This method takes `&mut self`, and so this closure can implement `FnMut`, too, as it only needs to take a mutable reference to `ssa`. If weren't using `move`, the closure would not own `ssa` even and just hold a mutable reference to it; but since you are using `move` you force the compiler to move `ssa` into the closure.

When calling the closures, the first closure implements `FnOnce`, and thus, when called, it is called with `FnOnce::call_once()` that moves the closure. If you try to call it again, it'll fail with "use of moved value".

But the second closure is called with `FnMut::call_mut()` (because the compiler always picks "weakest" trait to call with), which takes `&mut self`. That means it does not move the closure - thus you can call it twice, but on the other hand, you need to take a mutable reference to the closure - so it needs to be marked `mut`!

(If you're wondering why the first closure requires `ssa` to be marked `mut` while it moves it, indeed, notice that in the desugaring I commented out the `mut`. However, the compiler knows about closures and considers an assignment in a closure to require `mut` access, since it'd be very confusing if it did not.)

Answer (score 0):

A closure implements `Fn` if possible, `FnMut` if possible and otherwise only `FnOnce`. The first closure with `ssa = ssa.add("ds")` only implements `FnOnce` (since `ssa` is moved out from, and if `add` panics and the panic is caught, it is not replaced; so it cannot be called twice in the general case). The second closure with `ssa.add_assign("ds")` implements `FnOnce` and `FnMut`.

When calling a closure, the compiler will use the method from `Fn` (with `&self`) if implemented, otherwise the method from `FnMut` (with `&mut self`) if implemented, otherwise the method from `FnOnce` (with `self`). Only in the `FnMut` case is `let mut` required.